# Which game is it?

Tags: plot-explanation, revolver

At the beginning of the  movie [*Revolver*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolver_(2005_film)) (2005) we see the main character Jake Gree (Jason Statham) gambling with Dorothy Macha (Ray Liotta) and other people. It seems that they simply throw a gambling chip and for some reason there is a winner and a loser.

Which game is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### A coin toss

(Using a casino chip for a coin)

> "How much you got?"
>   "What's that got to do with you?"
>   "I'll toss you for it."
>
> (...)
>
> "I'll take red."